# Quickblox--placing/receiving a call while chat page is loaded--- Cordova

Tags: quickblox

we are building an application for chatting and audio/video calling using code for cordova.
In your (quickblox) video call sample, both users have to be in the video page to receive call from each other,
which means that if user1 leaves video page and user2 wants to call him so user 1 wont receive the call.
But in our app we need to allow user to receice call even if he is in chat page, so that we customize your sample to achieve this goal but when we add javascript files related to video call to those related to chat, the app stops loading chat history.
(i think that the problem is in "retrieveChatMessages(dialog, beforeDateSent)" function under "message.js" file )
How we can  fix this issue?

Thank you

Regards

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Questions need to include relevant code for anyone to be able to give you an answer. You mention a sample in your question - post that in your question, and then post what you've already tried to achieve your desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

*I think that the problem is in "retrieveChatMessages(dialog,beforeDateSent)" function under "message.js" file* - in the logs sould be an error.

The video-chat sample just for show the possibilities of video and audio calls.

You can call to your opponent with extension like dialog_id, which user from or other params that your need (or look in session object, may be it has all parameters which you need). And opponent recieve your call in **onCallListener** with this extension object and session (https://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-web#Make_a_call).

So the next logic:

- user1 call to user2 - `session.call(extension, function(error) {...})`
- user2 has incoming call to `QB.webrtc.onCallListener = function(session, extension) {...}`
- and user2 show for himself popup about incoming call (for example), if he accept call then he open dialog (that he took from parameters), build UI for call and send accept to user1 `session.accept(extension)`(https://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-web#Accept_a_call);

If I don't understand correctly, show errors from the console and we will continue...